# LINQ - find item in collection based on summation of fields

Tags: c#, linq

This question is a little difficult to explain, but I'll try to be brief.

I have a situation where I have a collection of key/value pairs, such as this.

```
class Foo {
   int Number { get; set; }
   int Value { get; set; }
}
```

so then I would have a collection set up like this...

```
var collection = new List<Foo>{
   new Foo { Number = 1, Value = 1 },
   new Foo { Number = 2, Value = 2 },
   new Foo { Number = 3, Value = 3 },
   new Foo { Number = 4, Value = 4 }
};
```

So I want to basically be able to find the number where the summation of all previous values is less than or equal to a given value. For example ...

If given a value of 3, then the Number returned should be `collection[1]`. (`collection[0]` has a Value of 1, and `collection[1]` has a Value of 2, which sums to 3)

I can accomplish this using several different lines, but I was wondering if LINQ is capable of doing it in a more succinct fashion.

Comment: If input was 4, then what is returned? Not all input numbers are composable as summation of continuous elements from the sequence.

Comment: Just hitting down vote on everyone does not encourage them to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

No, LINQ is not well-suited to doing this. It's *possible*, but you'd essentially have to use the `Aggregate` function and supply your own aggregate-creating delegates. It's much simpler (not to mention easier to understand) to do this:

```
int sum = 0;

foreach(var item in collection)
{    
    sum += item.Value;

    if (sum >= targetValue) return item;
}

return null;
```

Comment: @user1494736: I said it could be done, but in order to do it without causing side-effects like your solution does, you would have to use `Aggregate` and the code would be difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ does not generally encourage interdependency between elements (in this case, each element needing visibility to the sum of the elements before it).

It is much easier and clearer to write a loop to do this. You can put it behind an extension method to keep the functional feel:

```
public static Foo FirstBeyondSum(this IEnumerable<Foo> source, int value)
{
    var sum = 0;

    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        sum += item.Value;

        if(sum >= value)
        {
            return item;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var firstFooBeyond3 = foos.FirstBeyondSum(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why people kept telling you that LINQ isn't suited for this...

```
    var sum = 0;
    return collection.FirstOrDefault(item => (sum += item.Value) >= targetValue);
```

Maybe a > instead of the >= depending on the edge case, but you get the idea...

Or:

```
return collection.FirstOrDefault(item =>
    {
        sum += item.Value;
        return (sum += item.Value) >= targetValue;
    });
```

If you don't like the (sum += item.Value) >= targetValue hack...

Comment: While your solution is clever, it isn't suited for it because LINQ is intended to define *queries*, not actions that cause side-effects such as the one above. For instance, consider that instead of immediately calling `FirstOrDefault`, you defined the query separately, then ran it twice. You'd get different results for each execution, since your query causes side effects.

Comment: I agree that LINQ original purpose was to define queries... But it's a powerful tool, that you can successfully use for a lot of other purposes too..

Answer (score 0):

The exact question is:

> I can accomplish this using several different lines, but I was
>   wondering if LINQ is capable of doing it in a more succinct fashion.

The OP has already solved this problem by *not* using LINQ and is wondering if there is a LINQ solution that is better.  Therefore he **wants** to see a LINQ solution so he can evaluate if it's a better solution to his problem than not using LINQ.

So, here's the best I could come up with for a LINQ solution to the problem. Even if it turns out to be less efficient than his code, that will still be an answer to his question of whether LINQ is capable of doing it more succinctly and thus answer his exact question.

Also, the best way the OP can evaluate whether or not to use LINQ is to have an example. I don't see why he couldn't use LINQ.

To get the item from the collection:

```
var item = collection
    .Where((f,i) => value >= collection.Take(i + 1).Sum (c => c.Value))
    .Last();
```

If you're instead looking for the index of that item:

```
var index = collection.IndexOf(
     collection.Where((f,i) => value >= collection.Take(i + 1).Sum (c => c.Value))
    .Last());
```